# Can one properly embed a differential manifold into numerical space of double dimension?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

If $X$ is a $ C^\infty$ differential manifold of dimension $n$, then there exists an embedding $f:X\to \mathbb R^{2n+1}$.
This is a not too difficult  theorem due to Whitney, proved in many textbooks.
The interesting point is that $f$ may be chosen to be a proper map: the inverse image of a compact subset  in $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ is compact in $X$ or, equivalently, $f$ has closed image $f(X)\subset \mathbb R^{2n+1}$.
Now, many books go on to add that actually Whitney proved that $X$ may be embedded into $\mathbb R^{2n}$, but that the proof is much more difficult. (I don't know any book with a  proof of this sharper result)

I had always assumed that in the  sharper result the embedding was also proper but I was astonished to read, a few days ago, in Milnor-Stasheff's [Characteristic Classes](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Characteristic_Classes.html?id=5zQ9AFk1i4EC&redir_esc=y) (page 120) that in the embedding into  $\mathbb R^{2n}$ one may  **"presumably"**  assume that the image of $X$ closed, but that it is not proved in Whitney.
So  Milnor (one of the greatest topologists of all times!) didn't seem to be sure about properness in 1974 and I want to ask about the situation  today:

**Question**
Can an $n$-dimensional differential manifold be **properly** embedded into $\mathbb R^{2n}$ ?

**Edit:clarification of the question**
It is indeed very likely that the answer to the question is "yes", but I would like to be able to quote a complete proof in the literature.
I'm sure that such a proof is technically quite involved since  Whitney apparently could not come up with one while  Milnor and Stasheff in the quoted book seemed not to be   100% sure that the result is true (cf. their use of the adverb **presumably**).

Comment: @Igor: Ryan Budney very concisely sketches  a strategy for  modifying Whitney's proof into  one giving a proper embedding. Is there an actual proof in the literature ?

Comment: I second @Georges Elencwajg's request for a reference in the literature. I have never been able to find one.

Comment: Dear @Georges Elencwajg, I think this question might get closed as a duplicate of my question which Igor Rivin linked to. As such, if the existing answer to my question is insufficient for you and you really want a literature reference, you may want to edit your question to clearly explain that.

Comment: Dear @Ricardo: you are absolutely right and I have done exactly what you suggest.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31462/the-strong-whitney-embedding-theorem-any-recommended-sources

Comment: Whitney's argument in his self-intersections paper applies to arbitrary manifolds provided you start with an immersion that is "proper" (not in Whitney's sense, but in the sense that the pre-image of compact sets is compact).  The existence of such immersions follows from partitions of unity, and appears in the Guillemin and Pollack textbook.